# Is a CohFT completely determined by its high genus values?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, topological-quantum-field-theory

Suppose I have a CohFT, which is basically a vector space $V$ and a collection of maps $V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow H^*(\overline{M_{g,n}})$ satisfying certain properties under pull-backs by the gluing maps. Under which assumptions is it completely determined by its high genus values? High means with respect to the cohomology degree. I.e. for each $k$ I know the map $V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow H^k(\overline{M_{g,n}})$ for $g$ large enough for all $n$. And I want to reconstruct it for all $g$. I saw some  argument in a paper by Teleman which begins by saying that we can assume the genus is large, and then use the Madsen-Weiss theorem. So I wonder what's behind this trick and how to justify it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teleman's trick works as follows. Suppose I want to deduce $\Omega_{g,n}$ from $\Omega_{g+1,n}$.

Note that $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g+1,n}$ contains a copy of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$. It is constructed as follows. Take any fixed elliptic curve $E$ with two marked points. Now consider the locus of curves obtained by gluing $E$ to a stable genus $g$ curve at its $n$th marked point.

The factorization property of CohFTs tells you that $\Omega_{g,n}$ is equal to the restriction of $\Omega_{g+1,n}$ to this locus, contracted with the value of $\Omega_{1,2}$ on $E$, which is simply the cohomological degree 0 part of $\Omega_{1,2}$. So the subtlety is this: is the bilinear form $\Omega_{1,2}(E) \in V^* \otimes V^*$ invertible (nondegenerate)? If yes, you can deduce $\Omega_{g,n}$ from $\Omega_{g+1,n}$. If not, in general you cannot.

By some linear algebra one checks that the invertibility of $\Omega_{1,2}(E)$ is equivalent to $\Omega$ being semisimple, in other words, the algebra structure on $V$ given by $\Omega_{0,3}$ should be semisimple.

Comment: I am confused. You first say you fix E and two marked points, but then you seem to be integrating some form over E. Where is the 2-form on? How can a 2-form be invertible? Shouldn't it be a 0-form? Isn't it like: the degree zero part of a CohFT is a TQFT, and CohFT is semi simple iff the degree zero part is semisimple iff the handle element is invertible?

Comment: @AntonMellit $\Omega_{1,2}$ takes two vectors $u,v \in V$ and assigns to them a cohomology class of mixed degree on $\overline{\mathcal M}_{1,2}$. By the value of $\Omega_{1,2}$ on $E$ I simply mean the cohomological degree 0 part of $\Omega_{1,2}$, because $E$ is one point of $\overline{\mathcal M}_{1,2}$. The degree 0 part still depends on $u$ and $v$, so it is a bilinear form on $V$. (I will edit my answer to make this clear.)

Comment: @AntonMellit By invertible I mean nondegenerate (the matrix of the bilinear form is invertible). There is actually a good reason here for using the word nondegenerate. Indeed, in a TQFT $V$ and $V^*$ are naturally identified, so we can consider the handle element as a linear map from $V$ to $V$, and we need this map to be invertible.

Your last sentence about semisimplicity is exactly right.